# Eclipse requires Java 7 on OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-7

So I downloaded Eclipse and it said I needed Java 7, installed the JDK from Oracle and that works:

```
mike (~) java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

However Eclipse still shows the same error as before:

> Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required.

Is there some preference that eclipse could be reading to keep it trying to use Java 6?

Comment: Check in the about box, there is an output of startup sequence in there that will show the JDK that was actually used. It's likely that it's not using Java 7 that you just installed.

Comment: If you find that Eclipse is running with the wrong Java install, point it at the correct one by adding -vm [newline] [location] [newline] at the very start of eclipse.ini file.

Comment: I's hard to check the about box when Eclipse doesn't start.

Comment: I meant it in the context of your answer where you've disabled the version check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like you can trick Eclipse into working..

Right click the `eclipse.app` file > Show package contents. Navigate to Contents > MacOS and open `eclipse.ini`.

Comment out the line:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

With a hash `#` and then launch Eclipse. I presume this will only work if 1.7 is actually installed and available.

**Update**: After upgrading to Yosemite Eclipse no longer opened. So I uninstalled Java 7 and let it install Apple Java 6. It works fine.